# EditText: change images to string when copying?

Tags: android, copy-paste, android-edittext

I have an EditText that can contain images (emoticons). When I copy this text and paste it elsewhere, I get "obj" square instead of the image.

Is there a way to change what is to be put in clipboard when copying (so that I can change the image object into a string)?

**Edit 1**:
I guess I could create my own EditText class and override the method that is used when copying the text. Anyone knows what method should I override? I tried "getText()", but it doesn't work...

**Edit 2**:
Actually, it worked, but overriding this method changes the text in EditText, so it still isn't usefull...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be helpful:

```
public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case android.R.id.copy:
        // override copy
        return true;
    case android.R.id.paste:
        // override paste
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a byte array of the image?

`ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object

byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();`

Comment: I'm sending this message to server so that various clients can get it. If some of them cannot reinterpret it as image, they should see a classical emoticon symbol like ":)", and not a pile of thrash characters... That's one of the reasons I need to get String, not Spanned

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether you solve the problem or not. I just have a post at [stackoverflow_1527918](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11498209/1527918)

The method I used is to do a linear search on the `editText.getText().toString` to find the "obj" character. And then replace it with the image's link.

If you have any better idea, please tell me. Thank you.